# Sending a transaction - can I assume that when the 'data' field is missing, the 'gas' field should always be 21000?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas, gas-estimate

I have implemented a function for transferring ETH from my account to another account:

```
async function transfer(to, value) {
    let options = {
        from : PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
        to   : to,
        value: value
    };
    options.gas = await web3.eth.estimateGas(options);
    let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
    return await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
}
```

This is purely for ETH transfer; I am not trying to invoke any smart contract function, so I can omit the `data` field from the `options` object.

I've noticed that `web3.eth.estimateGas(options)` always returns 21000.

Can I count on that, and simplify my code to:

```
    let options = {
        from : PUBLIC_ADDR,
        to   : to,
        value: value,
        gas  : 21000
    };
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `to` address is not a smart contract, then yes. This is the standard gas cost of a simple ether transfer.

If the `to` address *is* a smart contract, even if you're not sending anything in the `data` field, a different gas amount could be consumed.

Comment: Indeed, my `to` address is not a smart contract, hence the `data` field is empty (and I now understand that an empty `data` field doesn't necessarily imply a non-contract `to` address). Thank you very much!!!